# TFS 2015 access via internet

Tags: visual-studio, tfs-2015

I have installed Team Foundation server 2015 on my server machine.
I have successfully created a repository and a project.I am also able to create a new project in visual studio and add to source control.
But the problem is when I try to connect to the TFS from my local machine it does not connects.When i Go to Manage Connections(from my local Visual studio team explorer) And add my server URL (Which i copied from server TFS management console) it says The remote name could not be resolved. Am I missing some configuration at the TFS Server configuration end..? 
Any Ideas!
Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: There are many reasons which could lead the issue you have. So please help me to better understand your scenario: 1). Is your local machine and tfs server in the same network and domain? 2). What is the VS version? 3). Which user account you used to connect to TFS?

Comment: the ping from name from local machine is pointing to ip of tfs ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the instructions for [configuring TFS for HTTPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Aa833872(v=vs.120).aspx). However, it would be far easier to use [Visual Studio Online](http://visualstudioonline.com). Every account gets five free users, and MSDN subscriptions at the level of Pro and above are also free.